# Nginx least_conn method session issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I use least_conn in Nginx, but when I open the application interface, it logs out. It doesn't do this in ip_hash method. What should I do for this?

Comment: it's probably related to your application session management

Comment: It 's working on AWS. There should be a configuration for that.